# Is it possible to import bokeh figures from the html file they have been saved in?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, import, bokeh

I've produced a few Bokeh output files as the result of a fairly time intensive process. It would be really cool to pull the plots together from their respective files and build a new output file where i could visualize them all in a column. I know I should have thought to do this earlier on before producing all the individual plots, but, alas, i did not.

Is there a way to import the preexisting figures so that I can aggregate them together into new multi-multi plot output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.0.2, there is not any existing API for this, and I don't think there is any simple technique that could accomplish this either. I think the only options are: some kind of (probably somewhat fragile) text scraping of the HTML files, or distributing all the HTML files and using something like `<iframe>` to collect the individual subplot files into one larger view.

Going forward, for reference there is `autoload_static` that allows plots to be encapsulated in "sidecar" JS files that can be individually distributed and embedded, or there is `json_item` that produces and isolated JSON representation of the document that can also be individually distributed and embedded.